# How to create a new bitmap after rotating

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I have rotated a image from landscape to portrait orientation.

My problem is that the image is very blurry when I use this code.

What I need to do?

```
// create new photo size:
if (b_IsRotated)
{
    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, fileStream);
    encoder.SetPixelData(
        BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
        BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
        525,
        700,
        DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
        DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
        pixelBuffer.ToArray());

    await encoder.FlushAsync();
}

_bitmap = new BitmapImage();
_bitmap.SetSource(fileStream);
```

Comment: You don't know any code that rotates the image. Please provide a good code example. If rotation is a material element of your question, please include the code that accomplishes that. Otherwise, please edit your question to remove the mentions of rotation. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blurriness is probably related to changing the size of the bitmap rather than the rotation.

You can control how the bitmap pixels are interpolated by setting the BitmapEncoder's [BitmapTransform property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.bitmaptransform.aspx). This will allow setting both the [Rotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmaptransform.rotation.aspx) and the [InterpolationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmaptransform.interpolationmode.aspx). By default the BitmapEncoder will choose an [InterpolationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapinterpolationmode.aspx) which emphasizes performance over quality, but if your need is for quality rather than performance you can choose a different one.